# Copy a table between 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, sybase

Is it possible to copy a table's values from SQL Server into Sybase 10? The tables are exactly same.
If it is possible, how? Is there any simple way?

I've read the post "How to Create a Linked Server" in SQL Server, but I don't get the point from there.

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean.  Copy a table value 1 time, or create a live copy of the table in the remote database that will show the most recent version of the table?

Comment: Hi, I've made a couple of minor changes to the text and title of your question to clarify a little, as well as remove a couple of tags that don't seem relevant and which might have caused you to get less attention to your question. If you don't like the edit, you can roll it back in the [revisions screen](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39842470/revisions).

Comment: You might also like to add a link to the article that you read, and explain what problems you had understanding it - that will make it easier for answerers to help you.

Comment: If the number of rows in the table is not overly huge, you can try generating data insert script using Squirrel Sql.